# Hotel doesn't say "No Visitors," but reviews do. What should I do?

Tags: hotels, new-york-city

I have NEVER in my life stayed in a hotel where it said visitors are not welcome. I am going to NYC, and my friend wanted to visit me, not spend the night. We have done this before at another hotel, but that one was all booked up.

So I made sure I read the policies for the hotel that I booked. It said nothing about visitors or anything at all really, but in two reviews of the hotel they said visitors weren't allowed. I am trying to contact the manager, but apparently the staff have pretty poor English. Can they charge me for my friend visiting? Or not allow him in at all?

I am not asking for anyone to spend the night only for a Visitor.

Comment: This isn't your question, but I'd be fairly skeptical of any NYC hotel that can't answer a straightforward question about their policies. While not every member of staff may have excellent English skills, the fact that nobody seems to be able to give you an answer is a red flag in and of itself.

Comment: @AakashM No, that's not me, I am not asking to share a room with someone. I am asking for a visitor, no nightly stay.

Comment: @ZachLipton I understand how that can be a red flag, but where NYC is so diverse it's kinda difficult. I have messaged the hotel again maybe I can get a response. One review said that there was a sign at the front desk that said "No visitors." I keep re-reading their policies and I see it no where.

Comment: I always thought *no visitors* was code language for *no escorts*, and that any other visitors are totally fine.

Comment: @Shaylene sure, but the same answers apply - their house, their rules.

Comment: @gerrit **Now** I am curious. How exactly do they know the person on the side of the customer is not an escort? Do they pass a "you are as female ugly enough to be not an escort" test?

Comment: @AakashM I understand that, but it was more or less is that even fair since they don't really say it anywhere in their policies. I will try to call them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've bought a date back to my hotel room before with no problem.  I didn't ask permission, just walked in like we were both guests there all the time.

If I've made arrangements in advance, I've also been upfront with the hotel about this, either when booking (ie. booking for 2), or at check-in asking for a duplicate key "for my friend who will be joining me later".  Never had a problem.

The key thing in my view is never give the room key back to the front desk until you check out.  That way, you are never showing up at the front desk (to ask for your key) with someone they have not seen before, but are instead just 2 guests walking across the foyer to the elevators.

That said, I have also stayed in other hotels where the house rules specifically say "no overnight visitors".  And yes, that is often in places that change different rates depending on the number of guests in the room.